# how to handle problem react native bottom navigation error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitly. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.

how to handle the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.